# Format existing date variable with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date variable (coming from an external source):

```
var date = '28/04/2017';
var time = '19:28';
```

It is possible to format these variables with moment.js (or without?) to variout formats?

Example: 04.28 19:28, 2017.04.28 19:28 or even Today at 19:28 (with moment().calendar();)

I tried

```
moment(date+' '+time).format('MM.DD.YYYY');
```

...but I am getting "Invalid date" error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using `moment(String)` method, but you're not passing a [Supported 
 format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) that it expects to parse.

You should use `moment(String, String)`, where the first String is the input date string, and second is the format of your input date String.

Try this:

```
moment(date+' '+time,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').format('MM.DD.YYYY');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
moment(new Date(date + ' ' + time)).format('MM.DD.YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the same [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```
var date = '04-28-2017'; // Month/day/year
var time = '19:28';
console.log(   moment(date, 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('MMMM D') ) // April 28
```